# jQuery's Ajaxnot calling success() neither error()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

The user of my Cordova/PhoneGap app has to sign in, so I group all the form's data into a Javascript array, then I `JSON.strigify()` it and I send it to the server via an Ajax request.

The PHP script has been tested by manually sending the CGI command, it does perfectly works.

Also, I used `alert()` to check if the function `sendDataToServer()` is called, it is.

The problem is that Ajax doesn't output `success()` neither `error()`. AND there is no difference (exept the command, obviously) with an other working script that I use for checking a login.

Note: I use GET for testing purposes, at the end it will be POST.

Here is the **WORKING** script:

```
$("#connectionFormSubmit").click(function () {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "http://" + host + "/my_app/check_login.php",
            data: "login=" + $("#login-conn").val() + "&password=" + $("#password-conn").val(),
            success: function (msg) {

                navigator.notification.alert(msg, alertDismissed, 'Result', 'OK');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                navigator.notification.alert(getError(jqXHR, exception), alertDismissed, 'Error', 'OK');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the **NOT WORKING** script:

```
function sendDataToServer(dataGuest, dataChild1, dataChild2, dataChild3) {

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "http://" + host + "/my_app/insert_new_user.php",
        data: "guest=" + dataGuest + "&child1=" + dataChild1 + "&child2=" + dataChild2 + "&child3=" + dataChild3,
        /* async: false, not changing anything */
        success: function (msg) {

            navigator.notification.alert(msg, alertDismissed, 'Result', 'OK');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

            navigator.notification.alert(getError(jqXHR, exception), alertDismissed, 'Error', 'OK');
        }
    });
}
```

(in both cases the server script works perfectly fine).

This is how I call the function:

```
sendDataToServer( JSON.stringify(dataGuest), JSON.stringify(dataChild1), JSON.stringify(dataChild2), JSON.stringify(dataChild3) );
```

I didn't find anything simiar to my problem on Google.

Comment: where is host variable in your function ?? `url: "http://" + host + "/my_app/insert_new_user.php",`

Comment: Any messages in the console? Perhaps CORS related? And to avoid problems with your variables, you should encode them or have jQuery do that automatically by sending an object instead of a string.

Comment: How about if you directly call your final URL in the browser (i.e. `http://[host]/my_app/insert_new_user.php?guest=[dataGuest]&child1=...`) ? Does it work ?

Comment: @HarshPanchal var host = 'localhost';

Comment: @roberto06 Yes it does

Comment: but in your script not define **host**  variable

Comment: **So I found the error**! I'm so sorry guys, my host variable wasn't reachable from where I was...

Comment: don't worry @MickaëlDebalme ....... no problem